# Caching object's properties

Tags: javascript, performance, v8

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var a;
a = { 
    b: { 
        c: { 
           d: 20 
        }
    }
};
```

And I have two functions for testing.
The first function doesn't cache object property in variable.

```
console.time('PROPS'); 
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) { a.b.c.d += 10; }
console.timeEnd('PROPS');
```

The second function cache **a.b.c.d** in variable **e**

```
console.time('PROPS');
var e = a.b.c.d;
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) { e += 10; }
console.timeEnd('PROPS');
```

In NodeJS I've got the following results:

Without caching:

- 312.526ms
- 311.120ms
- 311.955ms

With caching:

- 298.109ms
- 295.304ms
- 291.429ms

I expected such results... Next, I launched Firefox and tested there my functions, but I **minimized count of iterations** to 100000 instead of 100000000, because **my browser was crashed**:

Without caching:

- 153.31ms
- 145.85ms
- 146.4ms

With caching:

- 119.29ms
- 120ms
- 120.44ms

As you can see the second function is faster than the first... but when I started testing in Google Chrome I was confused about the results.

Without caching:

- 835.384ms
- 854.082ms
- 899.334ms

With caching:

- 1202.805ms
- 1251.734ms
- 1270.959ms

Why? I believe that if I cached the property of the object in variable I'd get more faster result, but not...

After several attempts to test my functions I went to the Internet. I found a few articles about improving performance in V8, but I didn't find that what I need.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Note that the code examples produce different results. In the second one, `a.b.c.d` is never changed. More realistically you should test `var x = a.b.c;` and `x.d += 10`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `e.d += 10` more faster than `e += 10`, but still worse than `a.b.c.d += 10`

Comment: don't optimize microbenchmarks.   http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html